# Assigning values to knockout observable dynamically determined by string name

Tags: knockout.js, variable-assignment, observable

I've got two questions please:

I'm using knockout (I'm a KO noob sry) and I would like to assign a value to a specific knockout observable upon a click event but which should be only determined upon the click event itself (and the value I will pass to the data-bind=click)...can it be done please...can I get the knockout observable variable just upon its name (a string value) instead of having to know which observable I'm going to be assigning a value beforehand?

And, secondly less immportant, if such a function ko.ObservableByName(stringName) exists is it possible to use it somehow and assign the pre-selection of multiple select items upon page load..and how please?

I've tried to do this...I've used **data-bind="click: loadData.bind($data, '*param1*', '*param2*')"** and then I'm able to get those *param1* and *param2* string values by constructing an event handler in my knockout viewmodel that goes something along the line of:

```
self.loadData = function (src, dest) {
    //dest is 'param1', src is 'param2', both are stings
    if (src == 'param1')
       self.p1observable($('#' + dest).val());
    else
       self.p2observable($('#' + dest).val());
}
```

My biggest problem with this is that I have to construct the function with p1/p2 observables already specified and hard-coded in it, but really I'd like to get param1 and param2 to be used as names or references by name of some of my observables, which I could then pass at will (alongside either a value to be assigned, or better yet another observable I'd like to copy the value from to the first one), and thus I could assign passed in values in the click function call directly to an observable of my choosing (and not have a large number of such small functions)...

Maybe I'm going at it the wrong way? Maybe I shouldn't be passing in string values at all... Maybe I should of tried to pass in an observable object, but how can one do that inside data-bind, do you just write myViewModel.myObservable or something like that?

Comment: Can you post an example of what you've got so far?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have your parent object, then you can access an observable by using this syntax:

`viewModel[observableName]`

and set the value like:

`viewModel[observableName](newValue)`

Here is a sample where you can choose the property name from a dropdown and then set the value accordingly and another one where the button is bound directly to setting an observable/value: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/CTnUQ/

Comment: that was almost exactly what I needed, so thanks lots...just a sidenote, if inside viewModel, use this[observableName] notation...but I'm guessing it's going to work if you're using it from outside of viewModel construct, what I'm not sure is, whether this would work if for example I had a number of different pages and each page would be loading an external viewModel script, would then numerous pages use the same data instances or would each one make its own copy of viewModel loaded from an external .js file? _I'll try that soon, I'm stuck by JQMobile, and its unsolvable changePage bug on WP7_